# Set Width of cell by number of lines in it

Tags: iphone, uitableview, nsstring

i have a cell and a `NSIntger` that counting number of lines in string. example:

```
case 1:
    NSString *string = @"abcde\nfghijk\nlmnopq\nrstu";
    NSInteger length = [[string componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:
                                 [NSCharacterSet newlineCharacterSet]] count];
    cell.detailTextLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:string];
    cell.detailTextLabel.numberOfLines = length;
    break;
```

this code is in `- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath`.

how i can set the cells width by `NSIntger` length?

Comment: you want to cell width or cell height??

Comment: This question is very ambiguous. I also don't see the reason for `[NSString stringWithFormat:string]`…

Comment: ahh.. yes.... sorry. i want the cell height.
and @H2CO3 - i just exampling the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to sell the cell height then you have a method call back method of UITableView delegate ...

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
   NSString *string = @"abcde\hijacking\nlmnopq\nrstu";
   NSInteger length = [[string componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:
                             [NSCharacterSet newlineCharacterSet]] count];
   return 44*lentgh; 
}
```

may this  will help you.

Comment: I did not get your point actually.. and if it is working you can right mark on this... and please explain what you want now exactly

Comment: i have you method. i want to set `UITableViewCell`'s height in the  `- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath` method. **how to do that?**

Comment: you can not set the height in cellForRowAtIndexPath: method.. apple provides you the separate delegate method for this task. this method heightForRowAtIndexPath: will execute for each cell..